# I would like to connect two Imac computers and use older one as a second screen. I would like to know how

Tags: multiple-monitors, cable, attachments

I have two 27inch Imac that I would like to connect. I would like to use the older one as a second screen. I am having a hard time getting this to work. Can someone help figure out what cables I might need? On the older Imac- there is a display port, firewire, and USB 2 ports. On the new Imac- there are USB ports and thunderbolt ports.  Can someone tell me what attachments or cables to buy to make this work?

Comment: Why do you think this will work? Do you have a specific source suggesting that it does? These are two different computers. You are trying to treat one of them like a monitor. That is not how it works. If you want a second monitor then you need a monitor and plug it in to some of the ports you mentioned.

Comment: Given the design of iMacs, which look at first blush just like a regular monitor, it is not unreasonable for someone to think *"I could probably use this thing that looks like a monitor as a monitor"* :)

Comment: Ironically, it was working with a display port cable. The arrangement feature showed. Applecare thinks I have a faulty cable and suggested a different attachment and cable. So if it's not supposed to work, why did it? And, why does the arrangement feature under display show up?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204592 is your best source of information.

Just double check that you have the correct iMac model. And especially the cables. Thunderbolt and Mini DisplayPort is physically the same cable, but they are different. So once you know for sure which cable you need (based on the info on Apple website) - get the correct cable.

Without knowing your exact iMac model (and year) - it would be impossible to give you exact answer.

To look up the iMac model - you can put your iMac serial number into here https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/